# Como somar/subtrair apenas alguns elementos de uma lista?

Tags: python, lista

Leve em consideração a seguinte lista:

```
enderecos = [1073741824, 1073741828, 1073741832, 1073741836, 1073741840, 1073741844, 1073741848, 1073741856, 1073741860, 1073741864, 1073741868, 1073741872, 1073741876, 1073741880]
```

Eu precisava realizar a subtração do número na posição 2 da lista menos o da posição 1, e assim por diante, e depois colocar os resultados em outra lista.

Comment: Acho que isso resolve: `[enderecos[i]-enderecos[i-1] for i in range(1, len(enderecos))]`

Comment: isso tá em python?

Comment: Sim, é um `list comprehension` Veja o item 5.1.3 da documentação nest [link](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html). Você pode atribuir a uma variável (`resultado = [enderecos[i]-enderecos[i-1] for i in range(1, len(enderecos))]`) e depois imprimir `print(resultado)`

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer esses calculos com o siguinte sistema de repetição:

```
enderecos = [1073741824, 1073741828, 1073741832, 1073741836, 1073741840, 1073741844, 1073741848, 1073741856, 1073741860, 1073741864, 1073741868, 1073741872, 1073741876, 1073741880]
NOVA_LISTA = []
POSICAO = 1
while True:
    if POSICAO >= len(enderecos):
        break
    SUBTRACAO = enderecos[POSICAO] - enderecos[POSICAO - 1]

    NOVA_LISTA.append(SUBTRACAO)
    POSICAO += 1

print(NOVA_LISTA)


RESPOSTA:
[4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).